# Why would free be reporting a freakishly high swap used value?

Tags: linux

I have seen twice recently RHEL 6 boxes showing a swap used value, reported by 'free', of something in the 10^15 bytes range.  This is, of course, far in excess of what is allocated.  Further, the '-/+ buffers/cache' line shows around 3 GB free.  Both of these machines subsequently became unstable and had to be rebooted.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might cause this?  Someone told me that this could be indicative of a memory leak, but I can not find any supporting information online.

Comment: If your memory runs full, there might be a memory leak ... or an application that needs more memory than your hardware provides. Use `top` or `htop` (there then `Shift`+`M` to sort by memory usage) to figure out what application uses up the memory.

Comment: The kernel in question is 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the systems running kernel-2.6.32-573.1.1.el6.x86_64?

Could be this bug:
access.redhat.com/solutions/1571043

Comment: This is not an answer, it seems more like a comment.

Comment: There's a kernel bug in that version which causes the exact symptom. It's rather unique behavior to this bug.

Comment: And that was neither an answer nor a comment. Sentences followed by a "?" are questions.

Comment: Suggestion for improvement: You should add your comment mentioning the kernel bug to your answer, instead of leaving just the question there.

Comment: Sorry about that. First time on stack. I didn't notice I as adding an answer. See it now. Thanks for correcting

Comment: The problem is fixed in 2.6.32-573.7.1, so our kernel (2.6.32-573.3.1) still has the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Linux moves unused memory pages to swap (see [linux swappiness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness)), so if you still have free memory (considering buffers/cache) you are good to go.

You probably have a process that is not used much and it was swapped out.